# Access to Path Denied - C# Directory.Move

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am working on a project that is to unzip folders, loop through the files in the extracted folders and uploaded data to a database, and move both the zip and file folders to another directory. I am running into problems with moving the extracted folder.

```
Message "Access to the path 'Insurance_Documents\\Test_2017' is denied."    string
```

My initial instinct was that it was a permission issue. However, I checked permission and all looks good; additionally, as the program creates the directory itself, it would not seem very logical for permissions to be the cause.

Next, after looking around the Internet a bit, I thought my uploadReportData() function might have been locking the files (it does utilize using statements, but I thought there might still be a "lag" during which the files were still locked). In response, I put the Thread.sleep statement in my code without success. The program moves the Zip folder just fine; it is the "normal" directory that is giving me trouble.

Program.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UploadInsurance.Helpers;

namespace UploadInsurance
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ZipHelper.processDirectory();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally {
                Console.Read();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

ZipHelper.cs (partial)

```
     static class ZipHelper
    {
        private static String BASE_DIRECTORY = @"Insurance_Documents\";
        private static String OLD_ZIPS = @"Insurance_Documents\Old\";
        private static String EXTRACTED_FOLDERS = @"Insurance_Documents\Inserted\";

        private static List<String> zipFileList = new List<string>();


        private static void getZipFiles()
        {
            zipFileList = Directory.GetFiles(BASE_DIRECTORY, "*.zip").ToList();

        }

        private static void processZipFiles()
        {
            String zipFolderName = "";
            String reportFolderName = "";


        foreach (String file in zipFileList)
        {
           folderName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            reportFolderPath= BASE_DIRECTORY + folderName;
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file, reportFolderPath);

            uploadReportData(reportFolderPath);             
            Directory.Move(file, OLD_ZIPS + Path.GetFileName(file));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Directory.Move(reportFolderPath + "//", EXTRACTED_FOLDERS + folderName);
        }
    }
 ... // MORE CODE HERE, INCLUDE uploadReportData function .. ///

    public static void processDirectory()
        {
            ZipHelper.getZipFiles();
            ZipHelper.processZipFiles();         

        }
```

I also tried changing

```
  Directory.Move(reportFolderPath, EXTRACTED_FOLDERS + folderName);
```

to

```
  Directory.Move(reportFolderPath + "//", EXTRACTED_FOLDERS + folderName);
```

but still received the error. I tried downloading and using ProcessExplorer (as noted in another answer here), and the only process accessing that directory is my program itself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

I apologize for the length, but I suspect the issue may lie in the below code:

```
 private static void uploadReportData(String folderPath)
    {
        String empFile = "";
        String reportFile = "";
        String spouseFile = "";
        String childrenFile = "";
        String beneficiaryFile = "";
        String visionDependentFile = "";

        Boolean hasEmployeeFile = false;
        Boolean hasReportFile = false;

        foreach (String files in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath).ToList())
        {
            if (files.Contains("employee"))
            {
                hasEmployeeFile = true;
                empFile = files;
            }

            if (files.Contains("report"))
            {
                hasReportFile = true;
                reportFile = files;
            }

            if (files.Contains("spouse"))
            {
                spouseFile = files;
            }

            if (files.Contains("children"))
            {
                childrenFile = files;
            }

            if (files.Contains("beneficiaries"))
            {
                beneficiaryFile = files;
            }

            if (files.Contains("vision"))
            {
                visionDependentFile = files;
            }

        }

        String employee;
        String report;
        String vision;
        String beneficiary;
        String children;
        String spouse;
        CsvFileReader reader;
        try
        {
            using (InsuranceModel dbContext = new InsuranceModel())
            {
                EmployeeReportData empData = new EmployeeReportData();
                Employee emp;
                Report newReport = new Report();

                if (empFile != "")
                {
                    report = reportFile;
                    employee = empFile;
                    employee.Trim();
                    reader = new CsvFileReader(employee);

                    List<String> employees = new List<string>();
                    while (reader.ReadRow(employees)) { }
                    String employeeID = employees[0];
                    emp = dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(em => em.EmployeeID == employeeID);

                    // see if employee exists in the database
                    if (emp == null)
                    {
                        emp = new Employee();
                        emp.EmployeeID = employeeID;
                        emp.SSN = employees[1];
                        emp.FirstName = employees[2];
                        emp.LastName = employees[3];
                        emp.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(employees[4]);
                        dbContext.Employees.Add(emp);
                    }

                    List<String> reportList = new List<string>();
                    reader = new CsvFileReader(report);
                    while (reader.ReadRow(reportList)) { }

                    newReport.Employee = emp;
                    newReport.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID;
                    newReport.Year = reportList[1];
                    newReport.DateSubmitted = Convert.ToDateTime(reportList[2]);
                    newReport.Action = Convert.ToInt32(reportList[3]);
                    dbContext.Reports.Add(newReport);


                    // add employees year specific data regardless

                    empData.EmployeeFirst = employees[2];
                    empData.EmployeeLast = employees[3];
                    empData.EmployeeGender = employees[5];
                    empData.EmployeeEmail = employees[6];
                    empData.EmployeeStreet = employees[7];
                    empData.EmployeeCity = employees[8];
                    empData.EmployeeState = employees[9];
                    empData.EmployeeZip = employees[10];

                    String locCode = employees[11].Trim();
                    Location loc = dbContext.Locations.First(l => l.LocationCode == locCode);
                    empData.EmployeeLocation = loc.LocationID;
                    empData.EmployeePhone = employees[12];
                    empData.InsurancePlan = Convert.ToInt32(employees[13]);
                    empData.VisionPlan = Convert.ToInt32(employees[14]);
                    empData.Status = employees[15].Trim();
                    empData.Report = newReport;

                    dbContext.EmployeeReportDatas.Add(empData);

                }

                if (childrenFile != "")
                {
                    children = childrenFile;

                    reader = new CsvFileReader(children);
                    List<String> childrenList = new List<string>();

                    while (reader.ReadRow(childrenList))
                    {
                        ChildReportData newChild = new ChildReportData();

                        newChild.Report = newReport;
                        newChild.ChildFirst = childrenList[0];
                        newChild.ChildLast = childrenList[1];
                        newChild.ChildDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(childrenList[2]);
                        newChild.ChildGender = childrenList[3];
                        newChild.ChildStreet = childrenList[4];
                        newChild.ChildCity = childrenList[5];
                        newChild.ChildState = childrenList[6];
                        newChild.ChildZip = childrenList[7];
                        newChild.Step = childrenList[8];
                        newChild.Foster = childrenList[9];
                        newChild.Student = childrenList[10];
                        newChild.Handicap = childrenList[11];
                        newChild.ChildSSN = childrenList[12];

                        dbContext.ChildReportDatas.Add(newChild);

                        childrenList.Clear(); // clear in preparation for reading a new row

                    }


                }

                if (spouseFile != "")
                {

                    spouse = spouseFile;
                    reader = new CsvFileReader(spouse);
                    List<String> spouseList = new List<string>();

                    while (reader.ReadRow(spouseList)) { }
                    SpouseReportData newSpouse = new SpouseReportData();

                    newSpouse.Report = newReport;
                    newSpouse.SpouseSSN = spouseList[0];
                    newSpouse.SpouseFirst = spouseList[1];
                    newSpouse.SpouseLast = spouseList[2];
                    newSpouse.SpouseStreet = spouseList[3];
                    newSpouse.SpouseCity = spouseList[4];
                    newSpouse.SpouseState = spouseList[5];
                    newSpouse.SpouseZip = spouseList[6];
                    newSpouse.SpouseGender = spouseList[7];
                    newSpouse.SpouseDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(spouseList[8]);
                    newSpouse.SpouseEmployed = spouseList[9];

                    dbContext.SpouseReportDatas.Add(newSpouse);



                }

                if (beneficiaryFile != "")
                {
                    beneficiary = beneficiaryFile;
                    reader = new CsvFileReader(beneficiary);
                    List<String> beneficiaryList = new List<string>();

                    while (reader.ReadRow(beneficiaryList))
                    {
                        BeneficiaryReportData newBeneficiary = new BeneficiaryReportData();

                        newBeneficiary.Report = newReport;
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiarySSN = beneficiaryList[0];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryFirst = beneficiaryList[1];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryLast = beneficiaryList[2];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryStreet = beneficiaryList[3];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryCity = beneficiaryList[4];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryState = beneficiaryList[5];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryZip = beneficiaryList[6];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryPercentage = Convert.ToDecimal(beneficiaryList[7]);
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryRelationship = beneficiaryList[8];
                        newBeneficiary.BeneficiaryType = beneficiaryList[9];

                        dbContext.BeneficiaryReportDatas.Add(newBeneficiary);
                        beneficiaryList.Clear(); // clear in preparation for reading a new row

                    }



                }

                if (visionDependentFile != "")
                {

                    vision = visionDependentFile;
                    reader = new CsvFileReader(vision);
                    List<String> visionList = new List<string>();

                    while (reader.ReadRow(visionList))
                    {
                        VisionDependentReportData newVision = new VisionDependentReportData();

                        newVision.Report = newReport;
                        newVision.VisionSSN = visionList[0];
                        newVision.VisionFirst = visionList[1];
                        newVision.VisionLast = visionList[2];
                        newVision.VisionDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(visionList[3]);
                        newVision.VisionGender = visionList[4];
                        newVision.VisionRelationship = visionList[5];

                        dbContext.VisionDependentReportDatas.Add(newVision);
                        visionList.Clear(); // clear in preparation for reading a new row

                    }

                }


                dbContext.SaveChanges();

            }


        }
```

Comment: If you are running the program under your account, try just creating the folder with code and doing the move manually while the program is still running. If you cannot move it manually, then your own program may be locking a file or something.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is indeed my program, but I am just not sure what section of the code is locking it. I will post my uploadReportData function as I suspect it might be that. Thanks so much.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use CsvFileReader via `using`, like `using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(children))
    {...}` to be sure the file handle is released outside the using clause.

Comment: Put the code in try catch block and check the exception as well as inner exception and stack trace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch says that you need to close / dispose the CsvFileReader object. Any stream to file will lock until you release it.

Comment: You and Alex J were absolutely correct. I am sorry I had to ask this question when the answer was so evident. I did not write the CsvFileReader class. Lesson learned - when using third-party code, make sure you understand how to use it properly. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the class (and thanks very much to the provider and all who make such code available for others). I suppose I just thought it closed/disposed its hold on resources when the "with" statement ended. Thanks again.